# Is there a way to have tweepy search method to not truncate tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So currently I am trying to collect tweets off of Twitter using the python library tweepy. However, I am having an issue with the code below bringing me all of the tweets truncated. I was wondering if there was a way to make it bring me the full tweets.

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = str(searchTerms), lang = 'en', count = 300, since_id = lastTweetId).items()
for tweet in tweets: 
    print(tweet.text)
```

Btw I did see that this `print api.get_status('862328512405004288', tweet_mode='extended')._json['full_text']` but the method I am using does not have a tweet mode param. Thank you for the help
I found the answer but tweepy api was not too clear on it and is why I got confused

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = str(searchTerms), lang = 'en', count = 300, since_id = lastTweetId, tweet_mode="extended")
```

Comment: You should post the solution as anwser and mark it has solved, good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = str(searchTerms), lang = 'en', count = 300, since_id = lastTweetId, tweet_mode="extended")